# How to solve the ERROR TypeError: xxx is not a function?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have a service that returns `Promise<???>` for all functions (btw is that a good practice?) e.g.

```
@Injectable()
export abstract class MyService {
  abstract getCategories(): Promise<Category[]>;
}
```

I have two impl, one local for testing in isolation and another remote for when deployed.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyServiceLocalImpl implements MyService {
  getCategories(): Promise<Category[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(this.data.categories);
  }
}
```

Now when I inject the service into a component I can't get hold of the `Promise` value as I get a runtime error:

```
import {MyService} from "../services";

@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  templateUrl: './some-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some-component.component.scss']
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  private service: MyService;

  private categories: Category[];

  constructor(service: MyService) {
    this.service = service;
  }  

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getCategories().then( categories => {
      this.categories = categories;
    });
  }  
}
```

Runtime error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.service.getCategories is not a function
```

**UPDATE** this is my `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
      cookieName: 'Csrf-Token',
      headerName: 'Csrf-Token',
    }),
    BootstrapModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    {
      multi: true,
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AppHttpInterceptorService
    },
    {
      multi: true,
      provide: MyService,
      useClass: MyServiceLocalImpl
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: The code you really have is probably not the same as the one you're showing us. Or you have several classes/interfaces named MyService, and are not importing the right one. Post a complete minimal example as a stackblitz.

Comment: Can you inject abstract classes and expect concrete implementations to be provided? I thought that was only possible in strict OOP languages. I.e. you are injecting `MyService` which is abstract and has no function called `getCategories()`

Comment: You are using MyService and it is abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multi: true` means that the "service" associated to the token is actually an array of service implementations.

Take the HTTP_INTERCEPTORS token, for example: it's used to reference **all** the HTTP interceptors. The http service gets all the interceptors as an array from the injector and calls them one after the other.